# Can I use jQuery's Deferred.promise() to replace an object's existing promise?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

According to the jQuery docs for `deferred.promise([target])`:

> If target is provided, deferred.promise() will attach the methods onto
>   it and then return this object rather than create a new one. This can
>   be useful to attach the Promise behavior to an object that already
>   exists.

As I understand it, calling `promise()` on a target should replace the target's existing promise interface, in which case I would expect the following to log `"new done"`:

```
var defer = $.Deferred();

defer.done(function() { 
    console.log('new done')
});

defer.promise( 
    $.getJSON('/foo').done(function() { 
        console.log('old done')
    })
);
```

But I'm still getting the target's original `done` callback. (Using jQuery 1.8.3.)

Is my understanding wholly incorrect, or is there some way to replace an object's entire promise interface in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're replacing the promise based interface of that getJSON call, but that replacement is occurring after you've initiated the request and already attached your "old done" callback.  Also, the original getJSON deferred is still the one that's resolved when the request completes which is why it's firing and yours isn't.

To accomplish what you're trying, you'd have to replace the interface before attaching any callbacks.  You'd also have to manually resolve the deferred that you're providing when the request completes.

Usually, something like this would work:

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();
var request = $.getJSON( "url" );

request.then(
  function() {
    deferred.resolveWith( this, arguments );
  },

  function() {
    deferred.rejectWith( this, arguments );
  }
);

// Now it's safe to replace the promise methods on the request
deferred.promise( request );

// This callback is being attached to the Deferred we provided,
// not the one managed internally by getJSON
request.done(function() {
    console.log( "Done!" );
});
```

This method is only safe for .done, .fail, and .always.  The other deprecated deferred handlers ( success, error, complete ) aren't handled by this example, although it's not difficult to fix that if you want.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helped clarify things. I have a [followup question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096350/can-i-manually-resolve-a-deferred-object-if-a-callback-might-need-to-reject-it) with an extra twist...