# Can I manually resolve a deferred object if a callback might need to reject it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to use a custom deferred object to manage some callbacks. I've figured out the easy case:

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();

deferred.done(function() {
    console.log( 'done' );
});

var json = $.getJSON('/foo');

json.then(
    function() {
        deferred.resolveWith(this, arguments);
    }  
);
```

But I need to inspect the response before resolving/rejecting. I'd like to add something like this:

```
deferred.pipe(
    function(response) {
        if (response.message === 'error') {
            return $.Deferred.reject(response);
        }
        return response;
    }
);
```

But when I do, my original `done()` callback is always called regardless. I'm pretty sure it's because once I call `deferred.resolveWith()` it's too late to "roll back" and mark it as rejected later. I know I could just move the conditional up into the first argument to `json.then()`, but that seems to miss the point of a deferred object -- I thought they were meant for encapsulating all of these behaviors into a single place.

Is it possible to put both the conditional and the callback into `deferred` while still resolving it elsewhere?

Comment: Just a note, `.pipe` has been depreciated in recent versions, use `.then` in it's place.

Comment: Where would deferred.pipe fit into your original code? I don't quite understand why you want to separate testing the parameters of the request from the request's done callback. As you have said, since it is already resolved in the done callback, you can't go back and reject it.

Comment: @KevinB deferred.pipe (or deferred.then) could go where the rest of deferred is defined, not after the ajax call. And my question might be a conceptual one -- maybe it's _not_ appropriate to encapsulate both the response testing and the callback in a single object? But in this case, that ajax call is itself nested in a bunch of conditionals and callbacks. Defining the workflow as a single object and just referring to it later seemed the best way to modularize it.

Comment: Is this closer to what you're trying to do? http://pastebin.com/v9XHmiGQ Setup the deferreds completely prior to sending the ajax request?

Comment: Why not just check response.message in the original success handler and call resolveWith/rejectWith as appropriate?

Comment: @KevinB Yup, that did the trick. Thanks! Post as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @dherman As mentioned, because I'd prefer to encapsulate all of that behavior into a single object. The original handler is deeply nested and I'd like to maintain the callback logic in a separate place for ease.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you goal is really just to separate out the functionality into two steps: validate the result of the ajax request, then handle the result. To do that, have an outer deferred that then gets replaced with an inner deferred that resolves or rejects based on the parameters returned by the ajax request.

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();

deferred.then(function(data){
    // new deferred that we will be returning
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    if (data.success == true) {
        deferred.resolveWith(data.result);
    }
    else {
        deferred.rejectWith(data.error);
    }
    // any following chained methods will affect this returned deferred object
    return deferred;
}).then(
    // done callback
    function(result){
        console.log("Resolved!");
        console.dir(result);
    },
    // fail callback
    function(error){
        console.log("Rejected!");
        console.dir(error)
    }
);

var json = $.getJSON("/foo");
json.done(deferred.resolveWith);
```